# Is it possible to format search results by having a results.php file refer to code in a main.css file?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

On a Wordpress website I have created using a template (Herald from Meks), I want to create a series of drop down menus which provide real-time filtering of posts.

I have installed several plugins that let me both create (A) the underlying taxonomy to use in the menus and (B) the drop down menus using the taxonomy which allow the filtering to occur.

The preliminary result of combining these approaches can be [seen here](https://www.exgeospatial.org/search-demo/). At this point, the taxonomies are empty, so the filters do not currently function (this, I know how to fix). The issue I am trying to tackle right now is the formatting of the results.

The filter plugin uses a results.php file to control the format of the filter results. I managed to change the code a little in this file (based on my limited knowledge) to control the formatting of the search results somewhat, so I know that the plugin is seeing the file and using the settings contained in that file.

The website template has a style in the main.css file that I would like to use to control the way in which the results are displayed ([so they would be formatted like this](https://www.exgeospatial.org/page/4/?s=bradt)). However, due to my virtually non-existent experience in php, I can't figure out how to reference the correct layout in the template's css file within the results.php file. Also, unfortunately, the website template does not use a results.php file to specify the formatting of its search results (otherwise, I might be able to copy the code and use it for the plugin results.php file).

Is it possible to format the search results of the filter plugin by having the results.php file refer to a layout that exists in the main.css file? Or would do I have to specify the formatting of the filter search results completely within the results.php file?

I very much appreciate any help people can provide and would be happy to post whatever portion of the code would be most useful.

The code from the main.css referring to the layout option I would like to use is shown here (as far as I can tell):

```css
}
.herald-lay-f,
.herald-site-content .herald-related .herald-lay-f {
  width: 100%;
  width: 340px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.herald-lay-f .entry-meta,
.herald-site-content .herald-related .herald-lay-f .entry-meta {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.herald-lay-f .entry-header,
.herald-site-content .herald-related .herald-lay-f .entry-header {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.herald-lay-f .entry-content,
.herald-site-content .herald-related .herald-lay-f .entry-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-header,
.herald-single .herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;
  margin-top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .meta-category,
.herald-single .herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .meta-category {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .meta-category a,
.herald-single .herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .meta-category a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
.herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-meta .meta-item,
.herald-single .herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-meta .meta-item,
.herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-meta span,
.herald-single .herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-meta span,
.herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-meta a,
.herald-single .herald-lay-f .herald-ovrld .entry-meta a {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Having a PHP script print out HTML to a browser is likely the most used method, so of course you can style the output via CSS.. write a static HTML page, rename it to a .php extension and insert PHP code as needed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Include a stylesheet tag referencing main.css in the HTML echo'd by results.php. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion!